# Android inflating child views causing skipped frames

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-inflate

My app contains a viewpager and each page fragment is laid out as so:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        ...
        other views
```

One of these 'other views' is a `LinearLayout` populated at runtime in a loop. Each item is inflated from xml. I've determined each call to `LayoutInflater.inflate()` is taking avg 4-6 ms. Between all my fragments and some containing more than one of these 'dynamically populated lists' i'm inflating 40-50 of these child layouts during startup and it's adding up to a lot of skipped frames.

I'm looking for a less expensive way to create all these views.

All the child views within one list are the same, is it possible to inflate one and copy it to another instance in a way that is faster than calling `inflate()`?

Is it possible to reuse these views similarly to the way a listview does?

One last potential solution, would it be faster to create these child views manually rather than inflate them from xml?

So to summarize the question, looking for the least expensive ways to create views in code. thanks for reading.

Comment: Use a `ListView`, `RecyclerView`, or some other adapter-based container. Not only are you wasting CPU, but you are wasting heap space, as many devices will not be able to show all your children at once. "Is it possible to reuse these views similarly to the way a listview does?" -- why are you *not* using a `ListView`, `RecyclerView`, etc. right now?

Comment: I have many other views above and between these lists. These pages are also constantly being updated (by nature of the app) with new views which may or may not be visible on all devices. You're right it would be best to use a listview but doing so would involve rewriting every pager fragment layout and class, which I may be doing soon but just hoping there was an easier solution to implement to fix the frame skipping.

Comment: Determine exactly where your time is being spent, using method tracing. If it seems to be in the XML parsing and stuff, then manual assembly in Java will be faster. My guess is that you'll find that the time is in things tied to the views themselves (e.g., setting up images) that is independent of how those views come into existence. If my guess is right, then your only option is to use fewer views, and it will be **substantially** less work for you to switch to something like `RecyclerView` than it will be to largely rewrite `RecyclerView`.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice. The frame skipping is 99% in the xml inflating. I'll try creating them manually and see if it helps at all. Otherwise looks like I'll be rewriting a whole lot of code.